# Can't refetch query useffect React native expo Apollo

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, hook, apollo

I'm currently devlopping an app in React Native and i decided to use Graphql and Apollo.
I have an issue in my login/logout component. I chose to do things this way :

- The google sign in btn trigger a function that goes fetch user's data in google db
- then when I've got results, I use the google_id to check if there is a user already register inside my db, if so I "navigate" to another screen, if not i Create a user, save it, and then I navigate.
- If the user want to logout he just has to click on logout btn.

My probleme here is that when i try to login/logout multiple time in the same expo session, sometimes the query doesnt refetch and i get stuck on the loading page.

I tried to solve this issue using skip property in useQuery => When the google's data come I dispatch a loggedInWithGoogle action which is a bool and I used it in skip value.
Then I tried lazyQuery and I used it inside a useEffect hook that is triggered when signInWithGoogle value changes.
I used some console.log to check if the getUser() function was called and from what i saw it was but the onComplete method is not called so i really dont know what's the problem here so if anyone can help ?

```
        useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
          console.log('response successful')
          WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
          const { authentication } = response;
          dispatch(loggedInWithGoogle(true));
          let accessToken: string | undefined = authentication?.accessToken;
          getUserInfos(accessToken);
        }
    
        return function cleanup() {
          setIsMounted(false);
        }
      }, [response]);
```

```
 const [getUser, { called, loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(
    GET_USER,
    {
      variables: { google_id: user.google_id },
      onCompleted: () => {
        console.log('request completed', data)
        handleData(data);

      }
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if(googleLogged) {
      console.log('fetching', called)
      getUser();
      console.log('fetched')
    }
  }, [googleLogged])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without seeing more of the code. But if a useEffect is not firing even though the state is changing, it's probably due to the limitations of the useEffect dependencies. Essentially **useEffect does not perform equality checks on the object properties**. So it does not necessarily recognize a change occurred.

If that's the issue try using a basic type as the dependency (such as a prop that changes on response), or even set the response to undefined once you're finished with it. If the object is small you can also JSON.stringify the object before it is stored.

Here's an article that explains the issue well
https://coletiv.com/blog/dangers-of-using-objects-in-useState-and-useEffect-ReactJS-hooks/

Comment: thanks for the answer but i finaly find out what wa the problem, I had to reset my redux state and that solver the issue.